# Is there an analogue of permit for Solana?

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to approve several tokens at once in one transaction on the Solana blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

The SPL token program has an `approve` instruction that allows a specified "delegate" address to transfer or burn up the the approved amount.

Here is a reference from the [solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-approve-a-token-delegate).

You can create a transaction with multiple `approve` instructions up to the transaction size limit (1232 bytes).

Here is an [Solana Playground example](https://beta.solpg.io/658204b6fb53fa325bfd0c68) with a single transaction that includes two `approve` instructions.

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  createMint,
  mintTo,
  createAccount,
  createApproveInstruction,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

// Playground wallet
const payer = pg.wallet.keypair;

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Authority that can mint new tokens
const mintAuthority = pg.wallet.publicKey;

// Generate new keypair to use as "delegate"
const delegate = new Keypair();

// Create new mint account using `createMint` helper function
const mint1 = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer, // payer
  payer.publicKey, // mint authority
  null, // freeze authority
  2 // decimals
);

// Create another mint account using `createMint` helper function
const mint2 = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer, // payer
  payer.publicKey, // mint authority
  null, // freeze authority
  2 // decimals
);

// Create Token Account for mint1 using `createAccount` helper function
const tokenAccount1 = await createAccount(
  connection,
  payer, // Payer to create Token Account
  mint1, // Mint Account address
  payer.publicKey // Token Account owner
);

// Create Token Account for mint2 using `createAccount` helper function
const tokenAccount2 = await createAccount(
  connection,
  payer, // Payer to create Token Account
  mint2, // Mint Account address
  payer.publicKey // Token Account owner
);

// Mint tokens to tokenAccount1 using `mintTo` helper function
await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  mint1, // Mint Account address
  tokenAccount1, // Mint to
  mintAuthority, // Mint Authority address
  100 // Amount
);

// Mint tokens to tokenAccount2 using `mintTo` helper function
await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  mint2, // Mint Account address
  tokenAccount2, // Mint to
  mintAuthority, // Mint Authority address
  100 // Amount
);

const approveInstruction1 = createApproveInstruction(
  tokenAccount1, // Token Account
  delegate.publicKey, // Approved delegate
  payer.publicKey, // Token Account owner
  100 // Approved amount
);

const approveInstruction2 = createApproveInstruction(
  tokenAccount2, // Token Account
  delegate.publicKey, // Approved delegate
  payer.publicKey, // Token Account owner
  100 // Approved amount
);

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  approveInstruction1,
  approveInstruction2
);

const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payer] // Signer
);

console.log(
  "\nApprove Delegate:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);
```

Specifically, here is where the two instructions are created and then added to a single transaction.

```
const approveInstruction1 = createApproveInstruction(
  tokenAccount1, // Token Account
  delegate.publicKey, // Approved delegate
  payer.publicKey, // Token Account owner
  100 // Approved amount
);

const approveInstruction2 = createApproveInstruction(
  tokenAccount2, // Token Account
  delegate.publicKey, // Approved delegate
  payer.publicKey, // Token Account owner
  100 // Approved amount
);

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  approveInstruction1,
  approveInstruction2
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code examples here?